# Getting the data which dynamically changing on angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie on angularjs, i have some problems about promise using with ng filling.

I want to access filled html data with javascript. But the data on the page can be change dynamically.

When click some button. It should be fill angular with changable data. Then will take the recent filled html source.

```
    array.forEach( function (id) {
        var promise = $http.post('http://postpagedomain.aspx?id=' + id).then(onComplete, onError);
        promise.then(function () {
            var html = $('#divframe').html();
        }
        );
    });
        var onComplete = function (response) {
            $scope.Info = response.data;
}
```

Bu it's not taking recent data cause of synchronous problem. How can i handle it?

Comment: remove promise. then()... and add error function...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking response of your http call in a variable, directly make http call. Something like:
$http.post('http://postpagedomain.aspx?id=' + id).then(onComplete, onError);

So, this will call the onComplete method when API returns success and write all your logic of actions to be performed once API call gets success in the function body of onComplete.
Also include a function of onError in your code to get any exceptions thrown by the API.
Your code can look something like:

```
array.forEach( function (id) {
    $http.post('http://postpagedomain.aspx?id=' + id).then(onComplete, onError);
});
function onComplete(response) {
    $scope.Info = response.data;}
```